# Receive error in onSuccessListner in when trying to upload an image to the drive

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a function to upload images to drive in kotlin. It is as follow.

***DriveServiceHelper class***

```
class DriveServiceHelper(private val mDriveService: Drive) {
    private val mExecutor: Executor =
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    private val TAG = "DRIVE_TAG"

    fun uploadFile(
        localFile: java.io.File,
        mimeType: String?, folderId: String?
    ): Any? {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, Callable<Any> { // Retrieve the metadata as a File object.
            val root: List<String>
            root = folderId?.let { listOf(it) } ?: listOf("root")
            val metadata =
                File()
                    .setParents(root)
                    .setMimeType(mimeType)
                    .setName(localFile.name)
            val fileContent = FileContent(mimeType, localFile)
            val fileMeta =
                mDriveService.files().create(
                    metadata,
                    fileContent
                ).execute()
            val googleDriveFileHolder = GoogleDriveFileHolder()
            googleDriveFileHolder.id=(fileMeta.id)
            googleDriveFileHolder.name=(fileMeta.name)
            googleDriveFileHolder
        })
    }
```

In my activity i call it as follows.

```
    var mDriveServiceHelper: DriveServiceHelper? = null

    private fun driveSetUp() {
        val mAccount =
            GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
        val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            applicationContext, setOf(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE)
        )
        credential.selectedAccount = mAccount!!.account
        googleDriveService = Drive.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            GsonFactory(),
            credential
        )
            .setApplicationName("GoogleDriveIntegration 3")
            .build()
        mDriveServiceHelper = DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService)
    }


 private fun uploadImageIntoDrive() {

        driveSetUp()

        val TAG = "image upload"
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, arrayList[0].uri)

        try {
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap is null")
                return
            }
            val file =
                File(applicationContext.filesDir, "FirstFile")
            val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos)
            val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()

            //write the bytes in file
            val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
            fos.write(bitmapdata)
            fos.flush()
            fos.close()
            mDriveServiceHelper!!.uploadFile(file, "image/jpeg", null)
                .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<GoogleDriveFileHolder> { googleDriveFileHolder ->
                    Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "Successfully Uploaded. File Id :" + googleDriveFileHolder.id)
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "Failed to Upload. File Id :" + e.message
                    )
                })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception : " + e.message)
        }
    }
```

But the problem is in the ***uploadImageTodrive()*** function ***addOnSuccessListener*** is displayed in red color and says ***Unresolved Reference: addOnSuccessListener***.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper class returns type `Any?`:

```
fun uploadFile(
        localFile: java.io.File,
        mimeType: String?, folderId: String?
    ): Any? { ... // Look at the return type
```

But it actually should return `Task<GoogleDriveFileHolder>`:

```
fun uploadFile(
        localFile: java.io.File,
        mimeType: String?, folderId: String?
    ): Task<GoogleDriveFileHolder> { ... // Non-optional Task<GoogleDriveFileHolder>
```